# Permission denied on /var/www despite adding user to the owner of directory

Tags: permissions, apache2

Hi brand new setup here.

```
ls -ld /var/www
drwxr-xr-x 3 www-data www-data 4096 Feb 25 18:10 /var/www
```

so above shows that /var/www belongs to www-data

I then add current user to www-data

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data ahdee
groups ahdee
ahdee : ahdee sudo www-data
```

however while in /var/www I tried this and still got permission denied.

```
echo "hi" > t.txt
mkdir test
```

A bit confused because the owner is www-data and ahdee belongs to that group so why can't I write to it?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you log out and log back in before you tried your test?

Comment: Group write is not enabled on the directory. `chmod 02775 /var/www`.

Comment: @doneal24 great thanks, as explained below group members have to write access

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first "www-data" is the owner of the file, the second "www-data" is the group.

In the `ls -l`, the first block shows the access rights:

```
drwxr-xr-x
d              it's a directory
 rwx           the owner www-data may read, write and enter the directory
    r-x        members of the group www-data (e.g. you) may read and enter,
               but not write in there (e.g. create a new file)
       r-x     others may read and enter, too, but not write.
```

So, you'd have to change the permissions, so that group members may write:
`chmod g+w /var/www`

Comment: This is perfect and also helps me understand a bit more, thank you. FYI for others, I had to relog back in to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I was close to open a similar issue, to me this fix didn't work, but I found a way around it.

My issue was similar only that chmod g+w fixed it for the first 3 directories but it was not working with the last one.

/var/www/mysite.com/html

So, when I landed to this thread I wasn't even able to create a file with www-data user in the www directory, applying the command suggested here made it work in www and mysite.com but in html it was not working.

So, what I had to do was to move the html directory to a placeholder name and I created again another directory but this time with www-data user.

```
sudo -u www-data mkdir html
```

This worked to create the directory which is not surprise cause chmod g+w helped the user to have access there, but then I ran:

```
sudo -u www-data touch ./html/index.html
```

This command finally worked, so there might be some remaining permission lock on the html directory that I renamed, I couldn't really pinpoint the exact thing that was blocking me, but doing the workaround unblocked me, I can keep working now.

I hope this help someone.